# Handle multiple delete events from grid with single events handlers asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid, eventhandler, radajaxmanager

I have two grid which contains delete button and I am using RadAjaxManager which will fire ajax request from client side to server side OnajaxRequest which contain event handlers and that event handler will call my delete event like below:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager2" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="RadAjaxManager1Resource1" OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager2_AjaxRequest">
                <AjaxSettings>
                    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager2">
                        <UpdatedControls>
                            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Grid1" />
                            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Grid2" />
                        </UpdatedControls>
                    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                </AjaxSettings>
            </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

 <telerik:RadGrid ID="Grid1" runat="server">
  ---
  ---
  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Action" UniqueName="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="130px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Remove1" Text="Delete" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Id", "javascript:return DeleteData(\"{0}\");") %>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

 <telerik:RadGrid ID="Grid2" runat="server">
  ---
  ---
  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Action" UniqueName="Action" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Remove2" Text="Delete" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Id", "javascript:return DeleteData(\"{0}\");") %>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>



 function DeleteData(Id) {
   var ajaxManager = null;
   var action = 'Remove';
   ajaxManager = $find("ctl00_cphMain_RadAjaxManager2");
   var arg = action + "," + Id; //Remove,1(1 indicates id of record to remove from grid)
   ajaxManager.ajaxRequest(arg);This line will fire below method.
  }



public event EventHandler RemoveEvent;
protected void RadAjaxManager2_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            var argument = (e.Argument);
            var stringArray = argument.Split(",".ToCharArray());//[0]="Remove",[1]=1
            if (stringArray[0] == "Remove")
            {
                RemoveEvent(stringArray[1], null);
            }
        }
```

After this it will call this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.RemoveEvent += Remove1_Click;
            this.RemoveEvent += Remove2_Click;
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
            }
         }

protected void Remove1_Click(object sender, object obj)
        {
        }
protected void Remove2_Click(object sender, object obj)
        {
        }
```

Problem here is both this events are calling but I just want to call individual delete events on click of Remove1 and Remove2 buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to subscribe to events in your code-behind i.e. no need of `this.RemoveEvent+=`. Instead write a single method called `RemoveRecord(buttonId, recordId)`. I have explained this approach in a step-by-step manner as below.

1. First change the markup for `OnClientClick`. Note that we will be passing the Id of the record to delete as well as the server-side id of the button being clicked to the JavaScript function `DeleteData`.

   ```
   OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Id", "DeleteData('{0}', 'Remove1'); return false;") %>'   

   OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Id", "DeleteData('{0}', 'Remove2'); return false;") %>'
   ```
2. Change the JavaScript `Delete` method. Note that we are now passing the server-side button id, so that in code-behind we can easily know which button was clicked.

   ```
   function DeleteData(Id, buttonId) {
     var ajaxManager = null;
     ajaxManager = $find("<%=RadAjaxManager2.ClientID%>");
     var arg = buttonId + "," + Id; //Remove1,1 (1 indicates id of record to remove from grid)
     ajaxManager.ajaxRequest(arg);//This line will fire below method.
   }
   ```
3. In code behind, include a single `RemoveRecord` method and there is no need of creating event handlers as you have done in your original code. So you should remove the following methods from your original code: `Remove1_Click` and `Remove2_Click` and also remove the code in `Page_Load` that subscribes to click events.

   ```
   protected void RadAjaxManager2_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
   {
    var stringArray = e.Argument.Split(",".ToCharArray());//[0]="Remove1" or "Remove2",[1]=id of record to delete
    RemoveRecord( stringArray[0], stringArray[1]);
   }

   //the method below will delete data
   private void RemoveRecord( buttonId, recordId) 
   {
    if(buttonId== "Remove1")
     {
       //code to delete record with id of recordId
     } 
    else if ( buttonId == "Remove2")
     {
       //code to delete record with id of recordId
     }
   }
   ```

**Another Approach**

If you have to have `RadAjaxManager2_AjaxRequest` in parent page and  delete methods in child page, then add the following code at appropriate places as mentioned in their titles. *But please note that the markup changes and JavaScript function changes mentioned in above approach also apply to this approach.*

**In Parent Page (just outside the class)**

```
public class RemoveEventArgs : EventArgs
{
public RemoveEventArgs ( string buttonId, string recordId)
{
   this.ButtonId = buttonId;
   this.RecordId = recordId;
}
    public string ButtonId {get;set;}
    public string RecordId {get;set;}
}
```

Also, in same parent page change the method `RadAjaxManager2_AjaxRequest` to what is given below.

**In Parent Page (change this existing method)**

```
 protected void RadAjaxManager2_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
 {
            var stringArray = e.Argument.Split(",".ToCharArray());//[0]="Remove1",[1]=1 OR [0]="Remove2", [1] = 212
            if (stringArray[0] == "Remove1"  || stringArray[0] == "Remove2")
            {
                 if(RemoveEvent!=null) 
                 {
                   RemoveEvent(this, new RemoveEventArgs(stringArray[0], stringArray[1]));
                 }
            }
 }
```

**In Child Page (change existing methods)**

```
protected void Remove1_Click(object sender, RemoveEventArgs obj)
  {
    if( obj!=null && obj.ButtonId == "Remove1") 
    {
      string recordId = obj.RecordId;
      //write your code for deleting


    }
  }
protected void Remove2_Click(object sender, RemoveEventArgs obj)
 {
  if( obj!=null && obj.ButtonId == "Remove2") 
    {
      string recordId = obj.RecordId;
      //write your code for deleting


    }
 }
```

Comment: Actually i have one page that is ParentPage.cs and this Onajaxrequest is on ParentPage.cs page.This Grid and my Remove1 and Remove2 method resides on Abc.aspx and i have inherited this abx.cs page from parentPage:public partial class Abc: ParentPage

Comment: So How to call this RemoveRecord from ParentPage.cs Page?

Comment: Put the C# code in parent page since the method `RadAjaxManager2_AjaxRequest` is in parent page. The grid can be on child page.

Comment: Yes. Both these methods should be in parent page - `RemoveRecord` and also `RadAjaxManager2_AjaxRequest`.

Comment: But if you shift `RadAjaxManager2_AjaxRequest` to child page then put all C# code in child page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103354/discussion-between-learning-and-sunil).

Comment: can you help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646158/how-to-properly-configure-delete-functionality-with-radajaxmanager-with-confirma

Comment: I have added an answer to the question you have mentioned in above comment.

Answer (score 1):

you simply just use the RadGrid_ItemCommand and pass the command argument with del button and change the command name for both remove her's a sample code for

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Actions">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="Button3" Style="width: 14px" Height="14px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Erase.png" runat="server" Text="Delete1" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');" CommandName="Delete1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Pid") %>' />
                                            &nbsp &nbsp
 <asp:ImageButton ID="Button3" Style="width: 14px" Height="14px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Erase.png" runat="server" Text="Delete2" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');" CommandName="Delete2" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Pid") %>' />

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>



    protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete1")
    {

    }
if (e.CommandName == "Delete2")
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but i have to use existing code only with radajaxmanager.So can you give solution in accordance to that